# Multiple COUNTIFS Conditional Formatting Excel

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting, countif

I have about 26 Conditional Formatting rules on a single worksheet, about 23 of them are COUNTIF functions that highlight duplicate rows based on a category greater than 1. Is there a way to condense these rules down? It seems to be making the worksheet a lot slower, as well as impacting some VBA code that I use to delete/ add rows inside a table.

Below are a few example formulas that count 2 criteria, and they all return the same color/format, also there are some instances where items in Column J need to be exempt, which is why I didn't write it to match ALL duplicates in Column J:

```
=AND(COUNTIFS($E$14:$E$17,$E14,$J$14:$J$17,"Critical")>1,$J14="Critical")
=AND(COUNTIFS($E$14:$E$17,$E14,$J$14:$J$17,"High")>1,$J14="High")
=AND(COUNTIFS($E$14:$E$17,$E14,$J$14:$J$17,"Low")>1,$J14="Low")
=AND(COUNTIFS($E$14:$E$17,$E14,$J$14:$J$17,"Pending")>1,$J14="Pending")
=AND(COUNTIFS($E$14:$E$17,$E14,$J$14:$J$17,"Under Review")>1,$J14="Under Review")
=AND(COUNTIFS($E$14:$E$17,$E14,$J$14:$J$17,"Open")>1,$J14="Open")
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You may need to give more examples. Also, do they all return different colors/formatting? Or is it all the same?

Comment: Yes they do return the same color/format. Column E is an identifying field, such as an account number, Column J is a drop down category field. If Column E returns the same account number, check if column J has the same category. I've also have added a few more formulas.

Comment: Well you can definitely combine a few of those rules by using `OR`, for example: `=OR(AND(COUNTIFS($E$14:$E$17,$E14,$J$14:$J$17,"Critical")>1,$J14="Critical"),AND(COUNTIFS($E$14:$E$17,$E14,$J$14:$J$17,"High")>1,$J14="High"),AND(COUNTIFS($E$14:$E$17,$E14,$J$14:$J$17,"Low")>1,$J14="Low"))`. Try that and see if it improves performance.

Comment: Getting a message that I may not use reference operators(such as unions, intersections, and ranges) or array constants for Conditional Formatting criteria. :(

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to highlight instances where an account number has the same category twice?

Comment: Yes, but there are some categories in Column J that are exempt from being a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to reduce your formulas, and I think it will probably speed things up.  Haven't tested it.

First Create a named range for the categories that you DO want to check for duplication:

[image: categories named range]

Your first conditional formatting criteria will force a stop if the category is not in the above list.

```
=COUNTIF(Category,$J14)=0    '<Set this one to "Stop if True", and don't set any format>
```

Your next conditional formatting criteria will check both column E and J for duplication.

```
=COUNTIFS($E$14:$E$17,$E14,$J$14:$J$17,$J14)>1    '<This only processes if the first condition evaluated to False>
```

Comment: When I introduced the second formulas, it would highlight the whole table, any thoughts? I made sure the first formula was below the second formula in the conditional formatting hierarchy.

Comment: I would recommend putting the `=COUNTIF(Category,$J14)=0` formula first, ***AND*** checking the box on the right that says `Stop If True`.  That way your main `COUNTIFS` function will never evaluate at all if the category is not in the list.

Comment: Also, double check both your `Rule` formula and the `Applies to` range in the Conditional Formatting Rules Manager.  Sometimes when you change the applies to range, Excel changes your formula, and vice versa.  Anytime I make a change to one, I double check the other to make sure it reads as I want it to.

Comment: Is there a way to do this for two Named Ranges? I have a list that will highlight based on 2 criteria, but I need to create another countifs function where I need to highlight based on 3 columns.

Comment: If I understand you right, you would just use the `AND` formula to put together as many as you like: `=AND(COUNTIF(Category,$J14)=0,COUNTIF(OtherNamedRange,$Z14)=0)`.  Just think of the first condtion (with `Stop If True`) as an IF statement.  IF column1 is not excluded and column2 is not excluded, etc... THEN run the subsequent conditional formatting rule(s).

Comment: FYI, you could also reduce this to one rule: `=AND(COUNTIF(Category,$J14)>0,COUNTIFS($E$14:$E$17,$E14,$J$14:$J$17,$J14)>1)`.  But I think it is more understandable when you split it into two.